# Could not resolve property in QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, exception, queryover

I have a method by QueryOver in Nhibernate3.1

```
 var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>().
 Where(person=>person.PersonIdentity.FirstName.IsLike(firstName,MatchMode.Anywhere));

 return q.List<Person>();
```

Now i have a runtime error by this message:

> Could not resolve property: PersonIdentity.FirstName of: MyNameSpace.Domain.Entities.Person

Why?

Comment: That should be an answer and not a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

my problem resolved by add JoinQueryOver in Query

```
var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>().JoinQueryOver(p => p.PersonIdentity).Where(k => k.FirstName.IsLike(firstName, MatchMode.Anywhere));
```

By help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362317/nhibernate-could-not-resolve-property-exception-when-using-queryover-works-on-qu?answertab=votes#tab-taop) :