# fluent mappings error with incorrect foreign key

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

My fluent mappings are:

```
        HasOne(x => x.User).ForeignKey("fOM_User_Id").Cascade.None();
```

My class is:

```
public class OrganizationMember
{
    public virtual int MemberId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int OrganizationId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual int UserId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public  virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual string Permissions
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual System.DateTime DateAdded
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I run the query:

```
        var assignableusers = _session.Query<OrganizationMember>().Where(x => x.OrganizationId == CurrentProject.OwnerID)
            .Select(x => x.User.Login);
```

which generated:

`select user1_.fU_Login as col_0_0_ from tOrganization_Members organizati0_ 
left outer join tUsers user1_ on **organizati0_.fOM_Id**=user1_.fU_UserID 
where organizati0_.fOM_Organization_Id=7`

but it should have been:
`select user1_.fU_Login as col_0_0_ from tOrganization_Members organizati0_ 
left outer join tUsers user1_ on **organizati0_.fOM_User_Id** = user1_.fU_UserID 
where organizati0_.fOM_Organization_Id = 7`

How can I fix this in my mappings?
from **organizati0_.fOM_Id** to **organizati0_.fOM_User_Id**

Comment: You probably need to do a JoinQueryOver - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362317/nhibernate-could-not-resolve-property-exception-when-using-queryover-works-on-q

Comment: @Sam: even though User is a property on the class organizationmember? that seems a bit odd...

Comment: I would have thought the child classes would be retrieved with the parent class

Comment: I usually use the LINQ NHibernate extensions which do work this way, but the linked question seems to imply QueryOver needs an explicit join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your relationship is a true one to one.

http://www.jagregory.com/writings/i-think-you-mean-a-many-to-one-sir/

You should probably use a `References` (many-to-one) instead.

```
References(x => x.User).Cascade.None();
```